# Highlighting missing unique pairs when compared to master list - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, validation, office365, conditional-formatting

On Sheet 1, I have a master list of data, with corresponding attributes. Some data has more than one attribute, some has only one, and there is a possibility of blanks. Attributes can be repeated when assigned to a different name.

I've posted some example data below, so we can all talk about the same cells/names etc.

On Sheet 2, there is much more freeform data input/analysis going on. Users are able to select a 'Name' from a dropdown menu using Data Validation, and are then able to select from the available attributes corresponding to that name, again using a dropdown menu. Names and attributes can appear in any order on Sheet 2.

It is important that all pairings are considered in the second worksheet.

Is it possible to use conditional formatting to highlight the 'Name' field (on Sheet 2) until at least one row exists with all possible pairings? In the example below, you can see that we have forgotten to put any info relating to the fact that Sally is Happy, and consequently 'Sally' has been highlighted to draw attention to the fact that there is some missing information.

[image: Example Data]

Current thoughts:
I already have a list of the attributes that match the corresponding name- this is what drives the dropdown menu on Sheet 2, and is generated in a background sheet when a name is picked on Sheet 2. I can count the non-blank cells in this range to find out the total number of pairs that are required.

I would like to then count the number of non-duplicate attributes that are on rows that have the same Name as the current row, and compare this value.

I'm expecting this to get into the realms of array formulae, but may be wrong...
I'm also expecting array formulae to not work directly with conditional formatting, and to require the use of a 'helper column' to drive the formatting. Let me know if this is incorrect?

Something along the lines of the below (formatted as pseudo-code for readability, but this should be read as a high level description, not actual code)

```
{Count the 1s in the array(AND(
'Check if it's a name match'
If($D$1:$D$10=[$ACurrent],[set flag to 1],[set flag to 0])
'Check if it's a unique value'
[somehow check array values set at 1 to see if there is a duplicate value in column E, and then set the array value to zero if so])
}
```

Does this approach make sense, and how would I go about constructing this actual formula?

I don't mind using VBA if required, but would prefer to avoid it if possible (company policy, sorry).

Comment: My approach would be using dictionaries. 1 dictionary adds the sheet 2 data, Each name with all their atributes (Name | Atributie1, Atribute2, Atribute3,...) and then loop through the master sheet data and check if the atribute exists on the dictionary, if not, highlight that name on sheet2.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would work for you a non VBA solution that highlights name and Attribute in Sheet1 instead of in Sheet2? It would highlight your left dataset (Sally, Happy) instead of highlighting in the right dataset

Comment: Hi @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - Yes, I'd be very interested to see that! I could adjust the user instructions to make that work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you want to highlight value `Sally, Happy` if that value does not appear in Sheet2, so you just need a COUNTIFS

> **[COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842)**

I've got this:

[image]

I've used a Conditional Formatin Rule based on my own formula. The formula I've used is:

```
=IF($B2="";IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$12;$A2;$G$2:$G$12;"")=0;TRUE;FALSE);IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$12;$A2;$G$2:$G$12;$B2)=0;TRUE;FALSE))
```

There are 2 COUNTIFS, because blank values are possible:

1. `IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$12;$A2;$G$2:$G$12;"")=0;TRUE;FALSE)` will count how many rows got same name and non blank attributes in Sheet2. If 0, then it will return `True` and highlight row.
2. `IF(COUNTIFS($F$2:$F$12;$A2;$G$2:$G$12;$B2)=0;TRUE;FALSE)` will count how many rows got same name and blank attributes. If 0, then it will return `True` and will highlight

With the initial IF you can blanks or non blanks attributes, just to make sure you count all posibilities of values.

I've uploaded a sample to mi Gdrive in case you want to download and get the formulas autotranslated opening at your PC.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Im4LoaK4EIvINBj7tfyEcYk9juWUp7zr

Hope you can adapt this to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted my own answer below building on your work here - I'm delighted to have a VBA-free solution.

Answer (score 1):

[@Foxfire And Burns And Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9199828/foxfire-and-burns-and-burns) helped me to solve my problem - I have modified his formulae slightly, to remove the double `COUNTIFS`, and to account for rows in the master data where both cells are blank - below is what I used.

```
=IF (OR($A2<>"",$B2<>""),
        (IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$12,$A2,$E$2:$E$12,IF($B2="","",$B2))=0,TRUE,FALSE)
        )
    )
```

This works by returning `TRUE` or `FALSE` from the following logical checks - if the final result is `TRUE`, then the formatting appears.

1. `OR($A2<>"",$B2<>"")` - Checks is either of the cells in the master are *not* blank. - If both cells are blank, this returns `FALSE`, and does not format anything (see `A10:B10`).
2. `IF(COUNTIFS($D$2:$D$12,$A2,$E$2:$E$12,[see point 3])<1,TRUE,FALSE)` - This counts the number of times that *both* the range `$D$2:$D$12` contains the value of cell `$A2`, AND the range `$E$2:$E$12` contains the value of cell `$B2`. If that number is `<1`, (zero matches), then the statement returns `TRUE` and implements the formatting.
3. `IF($B2="","",$B2)` - This nested IF statement checks if Cell `$B2` is blank, and returns `""` if it is blank, or keeps the value of `$B2` otherwise. This is because `COUNTIFS` would see the cell as a 'zero' when blank otherwise (see `A9:B9`).
4. I have not used a similar nested if to check if `$A2` is blank, because it *should not be blank*, so it's useful to highlight that the user has made an error in data entry here, too (see `A2:B2` - this will remain red once the user inputs a name, as it will no longer match `D2:E2`.)

Reference image below:

[image: Working Conditional Formatting]